# dart-sass making variables from key value inside @each

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I am using "sass": "^1.44.0" (dart-sass) with create-react-app. I have the following inside _colors.scss:

```
$app-colors: (
  'black': #232323,
  'blue': #1caac5,
  'green': #32bf73,
  'yellow': #ffb102,
  'white': #ffffff,
);
```

This is my _derivedColors.scss:

```
@use "sass:color";
@import './_colors.scss';

@each $colorName, $colorHex in $app-colors {
  $#{$colorName}-20: color.scale($colorHex, $whiteness: 20%);
  $#{$colorName}-40: color.scale($colorHex, $whiteness: 40%);
  $#{$colorName}-60: color.scale($colorHex, $whiteness: 60%);
  $#{$colorName}-80: color.scale($colorHex, $whiteness: 80%);
}
```

What I want to happen is to get 4 global variables that would scale the whiteness of each color inside $app-colors for a percentage value and be named appropriately. For example the first variable would be named `$blue-20` and would contain `color.scale(#1caac5, 20%)`.

When compiling my code I get the following error:

> ./src/components/common/CallToAction/style.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/components/common/CallToAction/style.scss)
> SassError: Invalid CSS after "...n $app-colors {": expected 1 selector
> or at-rule, was "$#{$colorName}-20: "
> on line 9 of src/style/_derivedColors.scss
> from line 4 of src/style/_variables.scss
> from line 1 of /Users/mihasustersic/Work/taia-app-react/src/components/common/CallToAction/style.scss
> @each $colorName, $colorHex in $app-colors {
>
> ------------------------------------------^

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from which resources did you base your code on, but according to the SASS official [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) a regular `@each` loop should look like this:

```
$sizes: 40px, 50px, 80px;

@each $size in $sizes {
  .icon-#{$size} {
    font-size: $size;
    height: $size;
    width: $size;
  }
}
```

Knowing that, you should be able to apply it to your scenario:

```
@use "sass:color";

$app-colors: (
  'black': #232323,
  'blue': #1caac5,
  'green': #32bf73,
  'yellow': #ffb102,
  'white': #ffffff,
);

@each $colorName, $colorHex in $app-colors {
  ##{$colorName}-20 {
      color: color.scale($colorHex, $whiteness: 20%);
  }
  ##{$colorName}-40 {
      color: color.scale($colorHex, $whiteness: 40%);
  }
  ##{$colorName}-60 {
      color: color.scale($colorHex, $whiteness: 60%);
  }
  ##{$colorName}-80 {
      color: color.scale($colorHex, $whiteness: 80%);
  }
}
```

Put my SASS code in [here](https://www.sassmeister.com/) and you'll see how it correctly compiles into CSS.